# How do I use rnn to forecast to n periods with limited data?

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, prediction, forecasting, rnn

So this is my 1st time trying to run a **small time-series dataset** through an **RNN**, but after a lot of searching, I haven't been able to find,

**1.** How I can use this to forecast to n periods ? (like in the *model.predict(start, end)* function in ARIMA.)

**2.** Is there a better way of doing this using NN ?

**details on the data is given as comments in the code below.** thank you.

```
'''
total timeseries data points = 39
frequency = Months
train = 36
test  = 3
Need to forecast 3 periods ahead upto 42, currently using forecast horizon as 1
Limited data so used all in a single batch
'''

periods    = 35
f_horizon  = 1
batch_size = 35

x_batches  = dfp1[ : (len(dfp1) - (len(dfp1) % batch_size))].reshape(-1, periods, 1)          # train data for t   periods
y_batches  = dfp1[1 : len(dfp1) - (len(dfp1) % batch_size) + f_horizon].reshape(-1, periods, 1) # train data for t+1 periods

#defining test data set
def test_data(testdata):
    test_x = testdata[ :(len(testdata)-1)]   # t
    test_y = testdata[1:len(testdata)]       # t+1
    return test_x, test_y

test_x, test_y = test_data(dfp3[-4: ]) #since 35 points were used in training, used the last 4 points for testing

outputs    = 1
inputs     = 1
hidden     = 100

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    with tf.variable_scope('var', reuse = tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        x  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, periods, inputs])
        y  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, periods, outputs])

        #creating a basic rnn cell
        basicrnn           = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(num_units = hidden, activation = tf.nn.relu)
        rnn_output, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basicrnn, x, dtype = tf.float32)

        stacked_rnn_output = tf.reshape(rnn_output, [-1, hidden])
        stacked_output     = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_output, outputs)
        outputs_           = tf.reshape(stacked_output, [-1, periods, 1])

        #using mape for loss fn
        loss               = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.divide(tf.subtract(outputs_, y), y))) * 100

        learningrate       = 0.001
        training_op        = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learningrate).minimize(loss) 
        init               = tf.global_variables_initializer()

        epochs = 1501

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            init.run()

            for i in range(epochs):
                sess.run(training_op, feed_dict = {x: x_batches, y: y_batches})

                if i%100 == 0:
                    mape   = loss.eval(feed_dict = {x: x_batches, y: y_batches})

                    print("ep %s: %s"%(i, mape))

            '''
            unable to pass the 4 test data points since input size is 35, 
            can I reshape x & y before I pass test input, would it alter the model ?
            also why is the loss fluctuating, and not steadily decreasing.
            '''

            #y_pred = sess.run(outputs_, feed_dict = {x: test_x}) 
            #print(y_pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 ways you can do this in NN -

1) take forecasted values ( horizon 1) and pass this again to built model to forecast next values ( horizon 2) and so on.

2) build a model with lagged values and have multiple output values( t, t+1, T+2... t+n). You need to decide window for lagged values.

3) use LSTM.

Answer (score 0):

use lstm instead of rnn.  rnn is better used for sequential pattern rather than trend data. rnn are good for translation of one code to another or one language into another.  they are not good for looking back or forward in a timeseries.